# Disable Ajax Effect

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using bootstrap-fileinput and it includes this file :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

All i want is to to disable Ajax animation,
Can anyone help ?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to provide any suggestion.

Comment: are you trying to disable the preloader mechanism?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes exactly I want to disable the preloader mechanism , I tried to delete this inclusion but I have lost some interesting effects , I tried to copy the contenent of this file that i found in the url but it  dosen't work

Comment: Any solution please :/ ?